# use Python to call a executable file and run commands of that file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have viewed some methods of calling an external program using python, the main method is to use subprocess, however I also want to execute the commands of that external program.

For example:

In python:

1. call that program;
2. execute command "operation1" (this is not a Python command but a command used in the external program);
3. print intermediate results;

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: Have you tried something before asking?

Comment: I have tried for 1 hour. Thanks anyway, I will keep trying, never use subprocess module before this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from subprocess import call
call(['someAppName', 'someArg'])
```

Can you just pass a command line argument to the application you're trying to run?

Comment: Does this have benefits over the `os` modules's  `os.system()`?

Comment: @Aesthete  I did something like this: subprocess.call(['./file_folder/./program', 'read ./A/file.v', 'print'])
If I run the read and the print commands directly in that program, I can print out what the program has read. But now I was only redirected to the program, and read and print are not executed. I use terminal to run the subprocess.call method instead of writing it to a python file then executing the python file.